# failed with laravel Controller/Model logic

Tags: laravel

My app contains 2 controllers and models of:

1. User
2. Flight

This is how they suppose to work together:

1. User logging in. [**Works**]
2. User clicks a button [**Works**]
3. Calling API METHOD with the user token: `startFlight()` [**Works**]
4. `startFlight()`: a new flight has added to the `flight` table.
   my API has to return the created flight details.

   - If flight already exists, return the user current flight
5. Make actions on the flight: Changing the flight color, music, etc..

The relationship between them is user `HasMany` Flight (Although actually user can be only in one flight)

- When the user finishes the flight, the flight is deleted from the flight table.

Since I noticed that when Im trying to play with 2 flights in the same time from 2 different browsers, The data changes in both browsers after every action! Then I noticed my controller logic is a disaster.

**Assuming I make an API call to `startFlight()` method in my controller:**

**My questions are:**

1. Since user will have only one flight assigned to his `user_id`, How am I supposed to detect the user current flight when calling `$user->flight();`?
   Currently it returns all the user flights via:

   ```
   public function Flight()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Flight');
   }
   ```
2. So, hopefully after solving question #1, when calling `startFlight()`, how I can create a new flight and return it if there are no flights, or if exists, return the existed flight?

Answer (score 0):

## 1

1. Your method should be named with pascal case - first letter should be small.
2. if You have relation with many flights it's better to named this relation `flights()`
3. after that you can make a call to recive an eloquent collection with: `$user->flights` (or `$user->flights()->get()`)

   Mention: `$user->flights` - this will create a relation in  user's model.
4. If You want to take current flight than You have to find it for example by some timestamp (like `created_at`), for example: `$user->flights()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first()`

   this is how You'll get the latest user's flight record or null value.

## 2

When You get the latest record as it's shown above - You check if its null or not and You can easily create it with: `$user->flights()->create($input)` where input is an array of input data.